# Changing color for navbar

Tags: html, css

How can I make the entire navbar black ? In this picture http://prntscr.com/cvgvxj  you can see that there are white borders and I can't figure out how to remove them/ make them black .

```
li:hover {
    background-color: white;
}
body {
    background-color: black;
}
.meniu {
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Metal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stil.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="J/js/collapse.js"></script>
        <script src="J/js/dropdown.js"></script>
        <script src="J/js/button.js"></script>
<nav class="meniu navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>


    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul> 
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: check this link:-http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp

Comment: check this link:-http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_navbar_vertical_active

Comment: make an inspect element in browser see you find any border bottom or something like that

Answer (score 0):

To change the background colour of the navigation bar itself, add this to the .nav class:

```
background-color:#002d60;
```

.

Comment: I fixed it with this tool http://work.smarchal.com/twbscolor/css/e74c3cc0392becf0f1ffbbbc0

Answer (score 0):

Actually border-color is the main issue; [see DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mfwj3zw3/). I also comment out where I have change see the css part.  And I make a html structure for you as a suggestion place all css link you have inside head tag `<head>`  and before the body tag all script tag you need to include.
[N.B: Don't use the !important part I used in css. I used !important because I overwrite the bootstrap css in same page to get snippet view. Read this [When Using !important](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)

```css
.meniu {
    background: black !important;
    border-color:black !important; /*Set the main nav border color black..Don't Use !important in your custom.css file*/
 border-radius:0 !important; /*By default it's 4px I change this coz on screen(>768px) It makes a border with 4px radius.. So the corners gets some white space..Don't Use !important in your custom.css file*/
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse{
  border-color:black !important; /*For Mobile Menu collapse background color black... Don't Use !important in your custom.css file*/
}
.navbar-nav li:hover {
 background-color: white !important; /*Don't Use !important in your custom.css file*/
   }
```

```html
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="meniu navbar navbar-default">
   <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul> 
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
```